# Trouble with extremely basic Isabelle/ISAR proofs

Tags: isabelle, isar

I am just starting to learn Isabelle/ISAR, and I wanted to try some basic logic proofs. My core issue is that even when I copy proofs straight out of an instruction manual, I am still getting errors. I am copying from the following pdf: [Isabelle Tutorial](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-39185-1_15)

Here is a very basic proof that works:

```
lemma "A ⟶ A"
proof (rule impI)
  assume a: "A"
  show "A" by(rule a)
qed
```

However, the following proof throws this error despite the fact that it is copied straight from a documentation slide.

```
lemma "A ⟶ A"
proof
    assume "A"
    show "A" .
qed
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoKxp.png)

The same is the case with this proof.

```
lemma "A ⟶ A ∧ A"
proof
  assume "A"
  show "A ∧ A" ..
qed
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJpBh.png)

I have no clue why proofs copied straight out of the pdf aren't working. Is it because I'm using a different version of Isabelle than the pdf? Or is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [prog-prove](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/prog-prove.pdf) instead of some old paper.

I don't know if the semantics changed since 2002 (which is possible), but `show` nowadays ignores the last fact. Instead you have to use `thus` or `then show`.

```
   assume A
   show A
      (*no assumptions*)
```

while

```
   assume A
   then show A
      (*we have the assumption "A"*)
```